# Why is my css class not firing upon initial load?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I have a bootstrap tabbed component on my page. I am trying to control which tab is active upon reload of the page. But, on initial load the behavior of the tab is very peculiar. Here is the code:

```
<li @(Model.tab == 1 ? "class=tab-pane active" : "class=tab-pane" id="tab1"><l1>
```

what it is showing in the markup and it is not working is (notice the active out outside the quotes

```
<li class="tab-pane" active id="tab1"><l1>
```

the behavior only happens on inital load, but it the tabs are pressed, the behavior is normal, but the extra "active" remains. I am confused where the active outside the quotes is coming from?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your output doesn't render the double quotes so it looks like this, where the `active` class doesn't get attached to anything but the browser will just see it as a standalone attribute:

```
<li class=tab-pane active id="tab1"><l1>
```

Instead try this:

```
<li class="@(Model.tab == 1 ? "tab-pane active" : "class=tab-pane")" id="tab1"><l1>
```

Comment: yep, this was the answer, I cannot thank you enough. I started to go down this path, but for some reason I didn't think this would work.